# Finite subgroups.

Tags: group-theory

(Index of a subgroup $H$ in a group $G$ is the number of distinct left cosets of
$H$ in $G$, it is denoted as $|G : H|$)

How to solve that problem.

> Let $H$ and $K$ be subgroups of a finite group $G$, satisfying $H ≤ K ≤ G$.
>
> Prove that $|G : H| = |G : K||K : H|$.